# Dropping duplicates in a dataframe while keeping the oldest record

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My dataframe looks like this (it says the time format is `datetime64[ns, UTC]`):

```
name     job      feedback    question    time
a        j1       False       q1          2021-09-06 09:25:03.659000+00:00
a        j1       True        q1          2021-09-06 09:35:03.659000+00:00
a        j1       True        q2          2021-09-06 09:24:03.659000+00:00
b        j1       False       q1          2021-09-06 10:25:03.659000+00:00
b        j1       True        q1          2021-09-06 09:25:04.659000+00:00
c        j1       True        q3          2021-09-06 11:25:03.659000+00:00
c        j1       False       q3          2021-09-06 09:00:03.659000+00:00
d        j1       False       q2          2021-09-06 08:25:03.659000+00:00
d        j1       True        q2          2021-09-06 11:24:05.659000+00:00
```

I want to only look at the `feedback`s that were given **the first time** a `question` was attempted by each `name`. So:

```
    name     job      feedback    question    time
    a        j1       False       q1          2021-09-06 09:25:03.659000+00:00
    a        j1       True        q2          2021-09-06 09:24:03.659000+00:00
    b        j1       True        q1          2021-09-06 09:25:04.659000+00:00
    c        j1       False       q3          2021-09-06 09:00:03.659000+00:00
    d        j1       False       q2          2021-09-06 08:25:03.659000+00:00
```

I tried:

```
deduped = df.drop_duplicates(subset=["name", "job", "question"], keep="first")
```

But it doesn't always work since the records are in random orders sometimes.

Is it possible to sort by time first and then keep my one-liner, as above? Is there any other safe way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your intuition was correct, you can `sort_values`:

```
deduped = (df.sort_values(by='time')
             .drop_duplicates(subset=["name", "job", "question"], keep="first")
          )
```

output:

```
  name job  feedback question                              time
7    d  j1     False       q2  2021-09-06 08:25:03.659000+00:00
6    c  j1     False       q3  2021-09-06 09:00:03.659000+00:00
2    a  j1      True       q2  2021-09-06 09:24:03.659000+00:00
0    a  j1     False       q1  2021-09-06 09:25:03.659000+00:00
4    b  j1      True       q1  2021-09-06 09:25:04.659000+00:00
```

Comment: I just managed to do it but I didn't know it was possible as a one-liner, thank you!

Comment: @futuredataengineer I reformated the code, this is called a pipeline (or method chaining). Very useful in pandas to chain many operations, a must-know ;)